# Download multiple images - can download all images but image are all the same

Tags: android, json, url, download, android-asynctask

My application gets image names from JSON. and I concatenated that name to another url to download image. I can download all images but all the images that I download are the same. example, my images name (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) but when I download, I can get it all but all are (1,1,1,1,1,1,1).

`DownloadImageTask` I had log String `name` and `reviewImageLink`. The result was fine. It show different name and url. BUT

`DownloadFullImageTask` on `onPostExcecute` I had also log String `name`, but it show the same name(1,1,1,1,1,1,1).

How can I download all my images and do not the same ?

JSON

```
{"pictures": [
{
    "picture_url": "2de19d49ecc640e94b1a306944e161ef.png"
},
{
    "picture_url": "bee57cbb42c364592e7472b442c58868.jpg"
},
{
    "picture_url": "b718041660189162080ff86b09370ec8.jpg"
},
{
    "picture_url": "7022dec80bb604bcbba51d28ce8bc31c.jpg"
},
{
    "picture_url": "0be79b2cd531adf02487e8d54f736c0f.jpg"
},
{
    "picture_url": "2101134bcfc1356df1ff187a8f9510f8.jpg"
},
{
    "picture_url": "2de62e026b3378bbbdfe687cd43d5b0e.jpg"
}]}
```

AsyncTask Download image and json

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    placeList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonO = jParser.getJSONUrl(url);

        // for " piture " Object in json
        pictures = jsonO.getJSONArray("pictures");
        for (int i = 0; i < pictures.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = pictures.getJSONObject(i);
            int cafe_id = jObj.getInt(TAG_CAFE_ID);
            String picture_url = jObj.getString(TAG_PICTURE_URL);

            // Table Picture
            Model_Insert model_Insert = new Model_Insert();
            model_Insert.setCafe_Id(cafe_id);
            model_Insert.setPitureUrl(picture_url);
            model_Insert = dataSource.createTablePicture(model_Insert);
            Log.i("pic", " Picture " + model_Insert.getPitureurl());
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_PICTURE_URL, picture_url);
            placeList.add(map);

            // Execute DownloadFullImageTask
            reviewImageLink = "http://xxx.xxx/xxx/place_pictures/"+picture_url;
            URL reviewImageURL;
            Log.i("url", reviewImageLink);
            String name = reviewImageLink.substring(reviewImageLink.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            try {
                reviewImageURL = new URL(reviewImageLink);
                if (!hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name)) {
                    isImage = false;
                    new DownloadFullImageTask().execute(reviewImageURL);
                    Log.v("log_tag", "if");
                    isImage = true;
                    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),getResources()
                                    .getString(R.string.directory));
                    sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, name);
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Directory created");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
     ShowAllContent(); // When Finish Show Content
}
```

}

AsyncTask execute url

```
public class DownloadFullImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap> {

protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... paths) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = paths[0];
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int length = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        byte[] imageData = new byte[length];
        int buffersize = (int) Math.ceil(length / (double) 100);
        int downloaded = 0;
        int read;
        while (downloaded < length) {
            if (length < buffersize) {
                read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length);
            } else if ((length - downloaded) <= buffersize) {
                read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length - downloaded);
            } else {
                read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, buffersize);
            }
            downloaded += read;
            publishProgress((downloaded * 100) / length);
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                length);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap created");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap not created");
        }
        is.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Malformed exception: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    String name = reviewImageLink.substring(reviewImageLink.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if (result != null) {
        hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name);
        saveToSDCard(result, name);
        isImage = true;

    } else {
        isImage = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: My first suggestion was wrong, sorry for that. I believe your error must be in the last part:saveToSDCard(result, name); Can you supply with some sample code?

Comment: here http://pastie.org/6408872

Comment: can you give more info about when it changes its value. Is it DownloadFullImageTask in postexecute or does it happen before? My suggestion right now is that the public variable reviewImageLink is changed somewhere else than in those two asynctasks...

Comment: In `DownloadFullImageTask` in `onPostExecute` the value of String `name` is (1,1,1,1,1,1,1) it's all the same. http://pastie.org/6409454

Comment: In onPostExecute of your DownloadFullImageTask you use the public field: reviewImageLink. But this field is changed by the other task. I'd recommend you put an inner variable in DownloadFullImageTask where you save paths[0] from doInBackground and use this instead. Try to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Ok now thank you so much. everything done. happy happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onPostExecute` of your `DownloadFullImageTask` you use the public field: `reviewImageLink`. But this field is changed by your other task. To fix this I'd recommend you put an inner variable in DownloadFullImageTask where you save paths[0] from doInBackground and use this instead.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance by multithread loading, memory cache or external cache. 
I suggest you take a look at this library

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It is powerful!

Comment: Another library to consider: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso). Very powerful and very simple to use.

Comment: How to use them to download images into sdcard. They just show images. and put them into a temporary folder. I am using Picasso.

Comment: Exactly I just want to download the images. Almost 1,000. I don't want to show them. And I want to download multiple images at the same time, not one by one.